# How to Click a button in an Iframe using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, iframe, puppeteer

I'm new to puppeteer so dont know much about it. This is my code so far and everything works.

But I want it to click the login button on the page after it has put the text in the fields, but I cannot figure out how to do it for the life of me. I've tried many different things and none work. Any help with this would be awesome.

just incase you need it
https://server.nitrado.net/usa/rent-gameserver

````
(async () => {
  console.log('launch browser');
  const browser = await pup.launch({headless: false});

  console.log('new page');
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  console.log('goto');
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
  await page.goto('https://server.nitrado.net/usa/rent-gameserver', { waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 60000 });
  await page.waitFor(5000);
  console.log('extract login iframe');
  var iframes = await page.frames();
  var loginFrame = iframes.find(f => f.url().indexOf("oauth.nitrado.net") > -1);
  await page.waitFor(5000);
  console.log('evaluate iframe');
  await loginFrame.evaluate(() => {
    document.getElementById('username').value = 'test';
    document.getElementById('password').value = '12345';
  });
  await page.waitFor(300000);

  console.log('done');
  await browser.close();
})()```
````

Answer (score 0):

I tried a workaround entering the frame url, I'm not sure if this will help, but here goes the code (main.js):

```
    const pup = require('puppeteer');
    
    mainFunc = async function () {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { //Wrap de promise
        var browser;
        try {
             //Wrap de tratamento de erros
            const browser = await pup.launch({ headless: false });
    
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            //SELECTORS:
            var userInputSel = '#username';
            var passInputSel = '#password';
            var loginBtnSel = '#auth_login_ws_header > form > button';
            var myUser = "myusername"; //PUT YOUR USERNAME HERE!!!
            var myPass = "MyPaSsWoRd123"; //PUT YOUR PASSWORD HERE!!!
    
            await page.goto('https://server.nitrado.net/usa/rent-gameserver', 
                            { waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 60000 });
    
            await page.waitFor(5000);
            console.log('extract login iframe');
            var iframes = await page.frames();
            var loginFrame = iframes.find(f => f.url().indexOf("oauth.nitrado.net") > -1);
            console.log(loginFrame.url())
            await page.goto(loginFrame.url(), 
                            { waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 60000 });
            await page.waitFor(5000);
            console.log('evaluate iframe');
            /*await loginFrame.evaluate(() => {
              document.getElementById('username').value = 'test';
              document.getElementById('password').value = '12345';
            });*/
            await page.waitForSelector(userInputSel);
            await page.type(userInputSel, myUser);
            await page.waitForSelector(passInputSel);
            await page.type(passInputSel, myPass);
            await page.waitForSelector(loginBtnSel);
            await page.click(loginBtnSel);
    
            await page.waitFor(300000);
            
            console.log('done');
            await browser.close();
    
          
        } catch (e) { 
          if(browser!=undefined){
            browser.close();//Close browser if error
          }
          return reject(e);
        }
      });//Wrap de promise
    }
    
    mainFunc();
```

This is a running version for you to test. Just type "node main". (of course you need puppeteer installed (npm i puppeteer))...

Comment: getting error ```internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\logan\Desktop\GamerBot\test.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []```

Comment: I edited it so it to add the whole code I used and it should be running fine, so you can test before extrating the parts you need...

Comment: just copied and pasted that whole code still giving the same error

Comment: never mind! got it to work! you're a legend!!!!!. but im trying to put it in my commands folder and rename the file and it wont work? My goal is to download the log files and read them to my discord server. dont know how im gonna do that yet but this is a start! ive been stuck on this for days and you just helped me out alot. so thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: how can i put that code into another file with it working? cause everytime i try i get errors.

Comment: This question is too vague, I don't know exactly what you want, you should try to search your problem and if there´s no answer you can open a new question at stackoverflow. Anyways, if you´re trying to use this function from another script you should learn to use "exports". And if my answer really solved your original question, remember to accept the answer so I can get some points and be happy :).